# How to redirect users based on their email addresses to a specific dynamic profile page?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

I'm making a social Media Website I have added Firebase Authorization in it by now. I want to redirect Users to there profile page based on their email address that they entered, but I don't know much about JavaScript and don't want to use PHP. I want to make it Using HTML, JavaScript and Firebase only. Profile page contains their profile photo and name linked with their Google account. There will be only one profile page that manages all the users

Here's my code

```js
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const auth = firebase.auth();

function SignUp() {
  var firstname = document.getElementById("fname");
  var lastname = document.getElementById("lname");
  var username = document.getElementById("username");
  var email = document.getElementById("email");
  var passoword = document.getElementById("password");

  const promise = auth.createUserwithEmailAndPassword(username.value, email.nodeValue, password.value);
  promise.catch(e => alert(e.message));

  alert("Signed Up");
}

function SignIn() {
  var username = document.getElementById("username");
  var email = document.getElementById("email");
  var passoword = document.getElementById("password");

  const promise = auth.signInwithEmailAndPassword(email.Value, password.value);
  promise.catch(e => alert(e.message));

  alert("Signed In" + email.value, "as" + username.value);
}

function SignOut() {
  auth.signOut();
  alert("Signed Out")
}

auth.onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    var email = user.email
    alert("Active user " + email)
    //is signed in
  } else {
    alert("No Active User")
    //no user is signed in 
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="formContainer">
  <br><input type="email" name="Email" id="email" size="25px" placeholder="Email Address">
  <br><input type="password" name="Password" id="password" size="25px" placeholder="Password">
  <br><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up!" onclick="signUp()">
  <br><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign In!" onclick="signIn()">
  <br><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Out!" onclick="signOut()">
</div>
```

Comment: Make an example of redirection please. For example, if I log in with "John", where should I be redirected?

Comment: I want to redirect them to their profile pages

Comment: @Starkhub, what do the profile pages contain? For example, if the name of the logged in user is displayed, why not check the name associated with that email and pull that from Firebase?  i.e. you have one profile page, but the content changes based on the logged in user.

Comment: Use `location.replace("https://www.yourwebsite.com/" + user)` or `window.location.href = "https://www.yourwebsite.com/" + user;` when you want to redirect. But what's the url of the profile page?

Comment: I'm also working on that but i want the profile page to have there profile of their email address and there user name on their email address

Comment: @Vinserello Can you please show me how to use this code

Comment: But do you "physically" want a "html" profile page per user or a single "html" page that manages each user?

Comment: I want a single page

Comment: You might be better off with a SPA framework such as Angular or React. It will be a pain managing this "single pages" as you application grows

Comment: Ok, any method would do then single page or multiple page per user

Comment: multi page means you need to create a literal file in the directory for every single user, that would be insane. I haven't met a single person in the industry who builds dynamic web applications in Vanilla JS. It is just not maintainable.  But if you really want to do it, you will have a javascript function which retrieves each `div` from the document i.e. profile page, username etc. and dynamically set the values based on the fetched user. It'll either refetch the user or you'll have to pass all the information in the URL. You can use the `window.location.href` as mentioned above to redirect

Comment: I just want it to work by any way that is easy to use for me but also easy to maintain so singles page

Comment: Just any way it works good will do but dynamic page would be better I guess